# c# network login

Tags: c#, networking

How do I perform a network login, to access a shared driver for instance, programmatically in c#? The same can be achieved by either attempting to open a share through the explorer, or by the net use shell command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

P/Invoke call to [WNetAddConnection2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385413(VS.85).aspx) will do the trick. Look [here](http://cticoder.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/msbuild-custom-task-drive-mapper/) for more info.

```
[DllImport("mpr.dll")]
 public static extern int WNetAddConnection2A
 (
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] NETRESOURCEA[] lpNetResource,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpPassword,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string UserName, int dwFlags
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Windows Identity Impersonation, take a look at these links
http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2005/03/21/400088.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/saurabhkv/archive/2008/05/29/windowsidentity-impersonation-using-c-code.aspx