# C# copy file to another directory using other domain/username/password

Tags: c#, file, authentication, dns, copy

In c# 2008,
I'm trying to copy a file to a destination path (for example \newserver\destinationFolder), that can be in another domain or using a different username/password than the current user. How can I specify these new network credentials before doing the File.Copy(...) ?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158492/c-network-login

Comment: Related or duplicate: [How to provide user name and password when connecting to a network share](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295538/3744182), [copy files with authentication in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17786037/3744182), [Copying files over network (requiring authentication)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2715625/3744182).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question but I dont think this is possible.   I believe this type of file copy from one domain to another ( where there is not a trust set up) would be considered security hole.

Some options:

1. Set up a trust between the domains and give rights to the current user
2. You could try a Shell execute command and see if you can make this work through command line parameters.  I was thinking "Net use" command.

Answer (score 1):

Look at LogonUser. Here's the pinvoke page for it:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.logonuser

Comment: That URL appears to be dead. Is this a correct replacement: https://www.pinvoke.dev/advapi32/logonuser ?

Answer (score 0):

MapDrive => Copy files as local user => UnmapDrive. Take a look [here](http://cticoder.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/msbuild-custom-task-drive-mapper/):

```
    protected int MapDrive(){
        NETRESOURCEA[] resources = new NETRESOURCEA[1];
        resources[0] = new NETRESOURCEA();
        resources[0].dwType = 1;
        int dwFlags = 1;
        resources[0].lpLocalName = _DriveLetter;
        resources[0].lpRemoteName = _Path;
        resources[0].lpProvider = null; 
        int ret = WNetAddConnection2A(resources, null, null, dwFlags);
        return ret;
    }

    protected int UnmapDrive()
    {
        int ret = WNetCancelConnection2A(_DriveLetter, 0, true);
        return ret;
    }
```