# C# - Write To File with credentials

Tags: c#

I have a wpf application that needs to write a file (from Byte[]) to a share on a server. I have a service account with permission to that share. Is there a way to do something like:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(path,bytes,username,password)?
```

Obviously that doesn't exist but my research has not turned up any answer.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786037/copy-files-with-authentication-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

You to [impersonate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka(v=vs.110).aspx) the other user and then write the file.

See: [WindowsImpersonationContext made easy](http://michiel.vanotegem.nl/2006/07/windowsimpersonationcontext-made-easy/)

Also check this [answer for impersonation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250145/961113).